# Почему не работает memory_usage из memory_profiler Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь измерить потребляемую методом память. Этот метод - поиск подстроки в строке грубой силой.

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


def bruteforce(text, pattern):
    for i in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1):
        x = True
        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            if text[i + j] != pattern[j]:
                x = False
                break
        if x:
            return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mem_usage = memory_usage(bruteforce('AAAB', 'AB'))
    print('Memory usage (in chunks of .1 seconds): %s' % mem_usage)
    print('Maximum memory usage: %s' % max(mem_usage))
```

Но при запуске данного кода возникает ошибка: psutil.NoSuchProcess: psutil.NoSuchProcess no process found with pid 2. Не могу понять, что это значит.
Однако, если запускать код, который ниже, то все работает.

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
from time import sleep


def f():
    # a function that with growing
    # memory consumption
    a = [0] * 1000
    sleep(.1)
    b = a * 100
    sleep(.1)
    c = b * 100
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mem_usage = memory_usage(f())
    print('Memory usage (in chunks of .1 seconds): %s' % mem_usage)
    print('Maximum memory usage: %s' % max(mem_usage))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что в [документации](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler#api) сказано, что у этой функции есть 2 режима. В формате как вызываете вы она должна мониторить процесс. Ваша функция вернула 2, вот она и пытается найти процесс с id=2.

Чтобы работало с функцией надо передать ей кортеж вида `(f, args, kw)`. Т.е. в вашем случае:

```
mem_usage = memory_usage((bruteforce, ('AAAB', 'AB'), {}))
```

После чего получим:

```
Memory usage (in chunks of .1 seconds): [19.3203125, 19.3203125, 19.3203125]
Maximum memory usage: 19.3203125
```

Comment: А такой вопрос, что если у меня будет не только bruteforce, но и еще 2 каких-нибудь, например abc1 и abc2. Есть ли возможность создать массив из названий этих функций?

Comment: Если надо все сразу, то определите функцию и измеряйте её. А уже в неё напихайте вызовов любых функций каких надо. Если надо последовательно, то цикл for.

Answer (score 2):

В memory usage нужно передавать не результат работы функции, а ее саму.

```
def a():
   return 1
a # function at 0x....
a() # 1
```

Смотрим офф документацию [тык](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) и пишем

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
memory_usage((bruteforce , ('AAAB', 'AB'), {}))
```

Comment: Когда вы пишете memory_usage(i : int) то он смотрит использование памяти процессом PID = i